# Iterating through a list without double for

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I am trying to iterate through a list like the code below, but I am kinda new in python and I would like to know if there is any chance to get over the two for loops. Is there any way to do so ? Thanks in advance

```
temp = [0, 2, 3, 4]
for index, pointer in enumerate(temp):
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        if i != index:
           print(temp[i])
```

Results :

```
2
3
4
0
3
4
0
2
4
0
2
3
```

Comment: What output are you looking for? The one you currently have?

Comment: "I would like to know if there is any chance to get over the two for loops." I'm not sure what this means, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I just want to know if there is a way to make it iterate faster

Comment: I don't know if everyone agrees , but some clarification on the goal of your code might help us help you better.

Comment: My goal is to get as fast as possible these elements and I want to know if there is something to avoid the 2 for loops and get the same output as I have in Results. Sorry if I am not specific it is my first question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp = [0, 2, 3, 4]
sol=[]
for i in range(len(temp)):
    sol.extend(temp[:i]+temp[i+1:])
print(sol)
```

output

```
 [2, 3, 4, 0, 3, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @M.Mar why accept the other solution? my solution is far faster than that one, i run that solution against mine for 1000 number upto 100 times and my solution is 75 seconds faster than that one. weird you asked  for less that 2 loops solution and accept 3 loop solution

Comment: "weird you asked for less that 2 loops solution and accept 3 loop solution" - But the answer marked as correct only uses one for loop with tuple unpacking...

Comment: @JordanSinger sorry my fault didn't ssaw range in it. you are correct , it's just 1 loop and tuple unpacking, as per OP require if you see functioning inside the product , you will find why i said so. plus this solution is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this handles your problem. I imagined this problem as printing the elements of a vector cross-joined with itself, without printing the elements along the diagonal of the resulting matrix.

```
values = [0, 2, 3, 4]

for index in range(len(values)**2):
    if index % (len(values)+1) != 0:
        print(values[index % (len(values))])
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
0
3
4
0
2
4
0
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `product` from `itertools`:

```
[u for i, (j, u) in product(range(len(temp)), enumerate(temp)) if j != i]
```

It depends on your list (all values need to be unique) but this also works for the given input

```
[v for u, v in product(temp, temp) if u != v]
```

Both give

```
[2, 3, 4, 0, 3, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3]
```

You can even turn both in an iterator by using round brackets instead of square ones.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you're trying to do is to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which is "Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops".

Just give the objects being iterated over as arguments, for example your code becomes:

```
import itertools

temp = [0, 2, 3, 4]

for (index, pointer), i in itertools.product(enumerate(temp), range(len(temp))):
    if i != index:
        print(temp[i])
```

Or since you don't appear to need `pointer`:

```
import itertools

temp = [0, 2, 3, 4]

for i, j in itertools.product(range(len(temp)), range(len(temp))):
    if i != j:
        print(temp[j])
```

The `itertools.product` function is named after the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Answer (score -1):

I propose the following solution. The solution used [list comprehension](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) .

```
temp = [0,2,3,4]    
(sum([ temp[0:x]+temp[x+1::]  for x in range(len(temp))],[]))
```

[image]

Comment: I might argue that this isn't very Pythonic. It's fairly hard to read.

Comment: Ok I understand @JordanSinger.  Probably the correct description is that I use list comprehension. What do you think?